# What is the best way of storing authors of books in database?

Tags: database, coding-style, standards

I have a table named `Book` and a table named `Author`. To link authors with books I created another table named `AuthorOfBook` where `Priority` is integer value which helps to get authors of every book in right order (1, 2, 3, ...).

[image: Before]

Is it good solution? First I thought storing more numbers than whole strings will help to save space, but then I added binary field with book's cover image, so now it doesn't matter. Should I remove `AuthorOfBook` table and add foreign key `BookId` to `Author` table? If I do it, my queries will look simpler and I will not need so many tables, but it will be harder to manage the authors.

[image: After]

And what about my `Priority` column? Is there any coding standard for that?

Comment: The first solution is correct. Stay with that.

Comment: You can use second solution only in the case - where you sure that book can have only one author. But Add FK of Author to the Book table

Comment: AuthorOfBook table is what adds your design support for case "A book can be written by more than one author". If you drop it , you will loose that many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first option is definitely the best and most correct one if you need to have priority. Priority is a property of the relationship, not the author, so it should not be on the author. What if an author has priority 1 on one book and 5 on another? :)

Comment: If I used second method, there could be more than one records in Author table with the same author names.